# Does Apache Ignite really need to use the very old version of sqlline which has issues & missing certain features?

Tags: sql, ignite, gridgain, sqlline, in-memory-data-grid

I see that Apache Ignite (and the GG editions for that matter) uses a very old version of sqlline which has issues & missing certain features. The version used is `1.3.0` which is from 2017, whereas the latest version is `1.12.0`.

The reason this comes up is because the old version being used in Ignite has certain issues & lacks certain features that are available in the newer versions. For example, sqlline's write to csv behavior (used for ignite cache export) prints each column value ONLY with a single quote and also records command begins with  printing the line “Saving all output to …”. With the newer versions we have settings for these like `!set csvQuoteCharacter '"'`, `!set silent true` , etc.

Now, we tried replacing the older version of sqlline (along with jline) and brought up a server node and did some basic testing. We did not see any issues.

So the question is does Ignite really need to use the older version (and that something is broken that we haven't hit in our testing) or can the newer version be used & is just a question of planned updates. If its the former please let me in on what could be broken & if its the latter do you folks know of any plans for this upgrade?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite and GridGain work well with most JDBC clients, so I don't see why it wouldn't work with newer versions of sqlline. It looks like Ignite uses version 1.9 ([since Ignite 2.10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13215)). I don't see any tickets to update to a newer version.

Comment: thanks for the helpful info & links, it looks like Apache Ignite & Girdgain's editions use different versions of sqlline. Meaning the ones used in GG seem to be older (`1.3.0`, as i mentioned in the description) than the `1.9` version used in Apache Ignite. Also looks like its just a matter of submitting a ticket first..